# Can Middleman in combation with rails solve XSS request failures

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, middleman

Im trying to create a javascript frontend whom should communicate with my rails backend. I figured installing Middleman would solve the annoying errors:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/groups.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4567' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Unfortunately it doesn't. I'm assuming because they're not on the same ports.

Is there a 'quick' fix for this; Or should I just add headers to my Rails project to avoid getting the XSS errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing [Rack-Cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) on your Rails backend is your best bet to resolving your 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' errors.

Running on the same ports wouldn't solve this straight out the bag as its a [security constraint of cors](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-security) and Middleman would'nt either.

Put simply to access `groups.json` you will need some form of [Cors Headers present on the server](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-adding-cors-support-to-the-server)